# Sufficient statistic for bivariate or multivariate normal

Tags: mathematical-statistics, multivariate-normal-distribution, exponential-family, sufficient-statistics

[Here](https://www.stat.washington.edu/jaw/COURSES/580s/581/LECTNOTES/ch13.pdf) on page 7, example 2.7. The claim is that sufficient statistics for $d$ dimensional multivariate normal $\mathbf{x}_i \sim N(\vec{\mu}, \Sigma)$  is $$\left(n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{x}_i, \hat{\Sigma} \right)\,,$$ where $\hat{\Sigma} := \sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{x}_i\mathbf{x}^T_i - \left(n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{x}_i\right)\left(n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{x}_i\right)^T$.

Where can I find derivation of this result? Thanks!

Comment: If you consider what "sufficient" means, your definition would likely lead directly to a simple method of deriving this result.  Which definition do you have in mind?

Comment: @whuber, Sufficiency in the sense that when conditioned on the statistic the distribution is independent of the parameters. Here I probably want to use the factorization theorem for the joint probability density of $n$ samples. That is  to construct statistics $T(\mathbf{x}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{x}_n)$ so that $f(\mathbf{x}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{x}_n; \vec{\mu}, \Sigma) = g(T(\mathbf{x}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{x}_n);\vec{\mu}, \Sigma) \cdot h(\mathbf{x}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{x}_n)$. I wasn't able to factorize this in the desired way, would appreciate if you could elaborate how I can do this. Thanks.

Comment: As a side, It would be nice to know if the statistic is also minimal sufficient.

Comment: (1) You don't have to construct statistics: you are given two of them and only need to show the joint probability can be expressed in terms of them. (2) If these two are not minimal sufficient, then a single statistic would be minimal and sufficient. It's easy to show that's not the case when $d=1$; the demonstration applies immediately to higher $d$.

Comment: @whuber. If I understood correctly your comments that's what I am trying to do. The exponential part of the multivariate normal is $\exp \left\{ -\frac{1}{2} (\mathbf{x}_i  - \mathbf{\mu})^T \Sigma^{-1} (\mathbf{x}_i  - \mathbf{\mu})\right\} $ so I am trying to factorize (product of exponents trough $i$) it so that the given sufficient statistics appears but I am not able to do this...

Comment: @whuber, I run into $\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{x}_i^T\Sigma^{-1}\mathbf{x}_i$, which I don't see if I can factorize further... Maybe I should look at  $(\mathbf{x}_i  - \sum_i\mathbf{x}_i + \sum_i\mathbf{x}_i - \mathbf{\mu})^T \Sigma^{-1} (\mathbf{x}_i  - \sum_i\mathbf{x}_i + \sum_i\mathbf{x}_i  - \mathbf{\mu})$...

Comment: Work it out for the case $d=1$ first so you can see what the algebra ought to look like without getting bogged down with matrices and vectors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As W. Huber tried to lead you to conclude, the sufficiency is a simple consequence of looking at the likelihood:
\begin{align*}
f(\mathbf{x}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{x}_n|\boldsymbol{\mu},\boldsymbol{\Sigma}) &\propto |\boldsymbol{\Sigma}|^{-n/2}\,\exp\frac{-1}{2}\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n (\mathbf{x}_i-\boldsymbol{\mu})^\text{T}\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}(\mathbf{x}_i-\boldsymbol{\mu})\right\}\\
&=|\boldsymbol{\Sigma}|^{-n/2}\,\exp\frac{-1}{2}\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n (\bar{\mathbf{x}}-\boldsymbol{\mu})^\text{T}\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}(\bar{\mathbf{x}}-\boldsymbol{\mu})\right\}\\
&\quad \times\exp\frac{-1}{2}\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n (\mathbf{x}_i-\bar{\mathbf{x}})^\text{T}\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}(\mathbf{x}_i-\bar{\mathbf{x}})\right\}\\
&=|\boldsymbol{\Sigma}|^{-n/2}\,\exp\frac{-n}{2}(\bar{\mathbf{x}}-\boldsymbol{\mu})^\text{T}\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}(\bar{\mathbf{x}}-\boldsymbol{\mu})\\
&\quad \times\exp\frac{-1}{2}\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n (\mathbf{x}_i-\bar{\mathbf{x}})^\text{T}\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}(\mathbf{x}_i-\bar{\mathbf{x}})\right\}\\
&=|\boldsymbol{\Sigma}|^{-n/2}\,\exp\frac{-n}{2}(\bar{\mathbf{x}}-\boldsymbol{\mu})^\text{T}\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}(\bar{\mathbf{x}}-\boldsymbol{\mu})\\
&\quad \times\exp\frac{-1}{2}\text{tr}\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n (\mathbf{x}_i-\bar{\mathbf{x}})^\text{T}\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}(\mathbf{x}_i-\bar{\mathbf{x}})\right\}\\
&=|\boldsymbol{\Sigma}|^{-n/2}\,\exp\frac{-n}{2}(\bar{\mathbf{x}}-\boldsymbol{\mu})^\text{T}\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}(\bar{\mathbf{x}}-\boldsymbol{\mu})\\
&\quad \times\exp\frac{-1}{2}\text{tr}\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}(\mathbf{x}_i-\bar{\mathbf{x}})(\mathbf{x}_i-\bar{\mathbf{x}})^\text{T}\right\}\\
&=|\boldsymbol{\Sigma}|^{-n/2}\,\exp\frac{-n}{2}(\bar{\mathbf{x}}-\boldsymbol{\mu})^\text{T}\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}(\bar{\mathbf{x}}-\boldsymbol{\mu})\\
&\quad \times\exp\frac{-1}{2}\text{tr}\left\{ \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}\widehat{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}}\right\}\\
\end{align*}
This likelihood thus only depends on two functions of the sample, $\bar{\mathbf{x}}$ and $\widehat{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}}$. $\qquad{ }$Q.E.D.

> **Note:** the author of the attached document should be identified. The more when he is the stellar statistician [Jon Wellner](http://www.stat.washington.edu/jaw/jaw.shtvita.html)!