# Is the Pearson Product Moment Correlation Coefficient (PPMCC) a sufficient statistic for a bivariate normal distribution?

Tags: correlation, pearson-r, sufficient-statistics

The PPMCC can be defined as the following:

$$\rho_{X,Y} = \frac{\mathbb{E}[(X - \mathbb{E}[X])(Y - \mathbb{E}[Y])]}{\sqrt{\mathbb{E}[X^2] - (\mathbb{E}[X])^2}\sqrt{\mathbb{E}[Y^2] - (\mathbb{E}[Y])^2}}$$

Is PPMCC a [sufficient statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic) for a bivariate normal distribution?

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/231714/sufficient-statistic-for-bivariate-or-multivariate-normal

Comment: Sufficiency depends on the statistical model, as the first line in your reference states.  What is your model??

Comment: @whuber, I think it not  even a statistic. A statistic is a function of observation that does not depend on any unknown parameters. I think $\rho_{X,Y} = \frac{\mathbb{E}[(X - \mathbb{E}[X])(Y - \mathbb{E}[Y])]}{\sqrt{\mathbb{E}[X^2] - (\mathbb{E}[X])^2}\sqrt{\mathbb{E}[Y^2] - (\mathbb{E}[Y])^2}}$ is not a function of observation and it may depend on some parameters? Am i wrong something?

Comment: @Masoud If by "E" you mean averaging over the data, then this is explicitly a statistic.

Comment: Given a random variable $X$ on probability space $(\Omega, \Sigma, P)$, $\mathbb{E}[X] \triangleq \int_{\Omega} X(\omega)\ dP(w)$ where $\omega \in \Omega$. The sample mean is an estimator of the expectation. I think of $X(\omega)$ as a theoretical (model) instance, rather than an actual observation which may be influenced by confounders not in the model.